# Extracting attributes from website and then removing duplicate elements in the list using pandas, bs4 in Python and writing it to a .xls file

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in Python Programming and I am practicing scraping different values from websites. I have extracted the items from a particular website and now want to write them onto a .xls file.

The web page has around 715 records among which there are duplicates. I have used the Panda module named unique() to remove the duplicate elements. It is taking a long time and the process is going on and on without ending. I do not have any clue whether it is removing the duplicate records or not. Kindly say where I am doing wrong and if possible suggest what to be done.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C+NSW+2000&radius=50%27%27&firstname=&lastname=&_so=contact', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

records = []

for item in data:
    name      = item.find('li', class_='agent-name').text
    position  = item.find('li',class_='agent-role').text
    phone     = item.find('li', class_='agent-officenum').text
    #link = item.find('li', class_='agent-name')['href']

    try:
        email = item.find('a', class_='val withicon')['href']
    except:
        email = 'No Email address'
    records.append({'Names':name,'Position':position,'Email':email,'Phone':phone})

for i in records:
    nl=pd.unique(name).tolist()
    pl=pd.unique(position).tolist()
    el=pd.unique(email).tolist()
    phl=pd.unique(phone).tolist()
    records.append({'Names': nl, 'Position': pl, 'Email': el, 'Phone': phl})

df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Position','Phone','Email'])
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\RayWhite.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do a loop. So instead of:

```
    for i in records:
        nl=pd.unique(name).tolist()
        pl=pd.unique(position).tolist()
        el=pd.unique(email).tolist()
        phl=pd.unique(phone).tolist()
        records.append({'Names': nl, 'Position': pl, 'Email': el, 'Phone': phl})


df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Position','Phone','Email'])
```

I would just take your list of dictionaries (`records`), convert to a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

then drop duplicate rows:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

I also added `.strip()` to your data to remove some of that white space that was coming up with the phone numbers and whatnot

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C+NSW+2000&radius=50%27%27&firstname=&lastname=&_so=contact', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

records = []

for item in data:
    name      = item.find('li', class_='agent-name').text.strip()
    position  = item.find('li',class_='agent-role').text.strip()
    phone     = item.find('li', class_='agent-officenum').text.strip()
    #link = item.find('li', class_='agent-name')['href']

    try:
        email = item.find('a', class_='val withicon')['href']
    except:
        email = 'No Email address'
    records.append({'Names':name,'Position':position,'Email':email,'Phone':phone})

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df = df.drop_duplicates()


df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\RayWhite.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking a long time because in the second loop, it appends to records while iterating on it, causing the loop to expand with each iteration. To fix your code, you need to change the variable name in the second loop.

So instead of using the "records" variable in the second loop like this:

```
records.append({'Names': nl, 'Position': pl, 'Email': el, 'Phone': phl})
```

change its name to something like "unique_records":

```
unique_records.append({'Names': nl, 'Position': pl, 'Email': el, 'Phone': phl})
```

Here's the fully updated code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C+NSW+2000&radius=50%27%27&firstname=&lastname=&_so=contact', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

records = []
unique_records = []

for item in data:
    name      = item.find('li', class_='agent-name').text
    position  = item.find('li',class_='agent-role').text
    phone     = item.find('li', class_='agent-officenum').text
    #link = item.find('li', class_='agent-name')['href']

    try:
        email = item.find('a', class_='val withicon')['href']
    except:
        email = 'No Email address'
    records.append({'Names':name,'Position':position,'Email':email,'Phone':phone})

for i in records:
    nl=pd.unique(name).tolist()
    pl=pd.unique(position).tolist()
    el=pd.unique(email).tolist()
    phl=pd.unique(phone).tolist()
    unique_records.append({'Names': nl, 'Position': pl, 'Email': el, 'Phone': phl})

df = pd.DataFrame(unique_records,columns=['Names','Position','Phone','Email'])
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\RayWhite.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```